# Play stereo audio source on Windows with mixing L and R channels and also adjusting balance

Tags: windows, audio

My use case:
As a real-time speech translator (form English to Russian) and streamer, I want to provide my listeners with individually balanced source-translation audio. Some of my listeners says they are fine with balance about 70R/30E but some of them want about 60R/40E.

As I understand the best way to do this is to stream audio where original voice and translation goes through different stereo channels, then with some kind of software let each individual listener to choose balance they desire and in the end mix those channels for the headphones scenario.

So my desired app would have these requirements:

1. can be installed on Windows 7, 8, 8.1, 10
2. is free for non commercial use
3. has some control for adjusting balance between audio output stereo channels (kind of slider control)
4. mixes stereo channels for Windows audio output (better for desired Windows audio playback device) where as result of this - sound volume levels are same in stereo headphones.
5. [optional] has configuration save/load feature that would help with installation for non advanced users.

My research:

1. Windows 10 has built in balance adjusting feature but it does not mix channels after that and does not keeps channels volume the same(SimpleSndVol app do this also).
2. [Equalizer APO](https://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/files/1.2.1/) can mix channels but I found not how to adjust balance between them.
3. Combining 1 and 2 also does not provide desirable result: channels are mixed before balance change. As result headphones volume levels are different but original/translation voice balance does not change in both headphones.